# SQL Server 2012 : create a new table with instant 1000 record that contains three @variable in int and varchar

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a new table with multiple variables: `@id` as `int`, `@lastname` as `varchar` and `@amount` as `money`. The three variables should change in a sequential manner

Example of expected result:

```
#id      #lastname    #amount
-------------------------------
1        Ben1         100
2        Ben2         101 
3        Ben3         103
.        Ben4         104
.        .            .
1000     Ben1000      .1000
```

I appreciate everyone's input

Comment: a `table` contains `variables` : that does not make sense. Or you mean `columns` ? use `CREATE TABLE` statement to create a variable. If you are not sure how, refer to the Books On Line or search for it

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is similar to "How To Create a Tally Table" problem. A sample solution is below:

```
WITH Tally (n) AS (
     -- 1000 rows
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
     FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
   )
-- INSERT INTO [TableOfYourChoice]
SELECT n, 'Ben' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, n ), n + 100
FROM Tally;
```

**Note:** if you want amount to start from 100, then change n + 100 to n + 99

Example adapted from examples at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
;with t as (
select 1 id, 'Ben'+cast(1 as varchar) name, 100 amount
union all
select id+1,'Ben'+cast(id+1 as varchar),amount+1
from t
where id<1000
)
--insert dbo.myTable
select * from t
option (maxrecursion 1000)
```

Comment: It worked perfect.Thank you very much  for your time