# SQL Server using a sequence in conjunction with union selects

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id AS INTEGER START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

WITH source (Id, SomeColumn) AS
(
          SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR id, 'some value 1'
          UNION
          SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR id, 'some value 2'
)
SELECT * FROM source;

DROP SEQUENCE id;
```

It throws the following error:

> NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default
>   objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined
>   aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table
>   expressions, derived tables or return statements.

Why does the `NEXT VALUE FOR` function not work with `unions`?
What is a good alternative?

I am using a similar CTE to seed a table with default values using a merge statement. I am trying to avoid manually typing in a sequence of numbers.

I need something like UNION SELECT id++

Comment: How does this "not work"?  Please provide the details.

Comment: Have you considered ROW_NUMBER() window function? Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287657/sql-server-2012-create-a-new-table-with-instant-1000-record-that-contains-thre/37288556#37288556?

Comment: Would this old-fashioned solution work for you?
CREATE TABLE #h (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), somevalue VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #h ( somevalue )
SELECT 'some value 1' AS somevalue
UNION 
SELECT 'some value 2'

SELECT * FROM #h H

Comment: ROW_NUMBER requires ordering by something. I would like to keep the original order.

Comment: why dont you consider a table variable or temp. table with an identity column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Alex's comment and link to a similar problem here is the solution:

```
WITH source (SomeColumn) AS
(
          SELECT 'some value 1'
    UNION SELECT 'some value 2'
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), SomeColumn FROM source;
```

For future reference: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` is the way to get row numbers without ordering a set